# VBA Range.Rows.Count giving unexpected results

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Range variable that contains an address - $2:$2,$4:$205,$214:$214 - (3 groups of rows).

I would like to get the count of all the rows in that range.

However,  range.Count gives me the count of all the cells (50,000~)  and range.Rows.Count only return 1 - the count of all the rows in the first group.  How do I get the count of all the rows

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim rowCount As Long
Dim ctr As Long

'You could use your range variable in place of Selection below
For ctr = 1 To Selection.Areas.Count
    rowCount = rowCount + Selection.Areas(ctr).Rows.Count
Next
Debug.Print rowCount
```